# Programming a REST client - is there a framework similar to Axis/JAX-WS for SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, rest, frameworks, jersey

Now I am learning how to build REST webservices - I am trying to build a REST service which communicates through XML (not JSON).

I am using the tutorial here.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

I have created a GET API which returns a List of ToDoes

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML })
public List<ToDo> getXML() 
{
    ArrayList<ToDo> al = new ArrayList<ToDo>();

    ToDo t = new ToDo();
    t.setSummary("First ToDo");
    t.setDescription("This is my first ToDo");
    al.add(t);

    t.setSummary("2nd Todo");
    t.setDescription("This is my 2nd Todo");
    al.add(t);

    return al;
}
```

I have a client program which calls this method

```
String xmlAnswer =   

 target.path("rest").path("hello").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);
```

I get the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<toDoes>
    <toDo>
        <description>This is my 2nd Todo</description>
        <summary>2nd Todo</summary>
    </toDo>
    <toDo>
        <description>This is my 2nd Todo</description>
        <summary>2nd Todo</summary></toDo>
    </toDoes>
</toDoes>
```

However, I am sure there is an easier way to program the client - I want to get an array of ToDo objects instead of XML. How do I do this? How to I generate the stub for a client ToDo class & how do I get the answer in the form of an array of ToDo objects?

Comment: Use `List<Todo> todos = ...get(new GenericType<List<Todo>>(){});`

Comment: @peeskillet - that was very useful.

Comment: @peeskillet - I took the output XML - used http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html to create an XSD from it - then used xjc to create a ToDoes class & then called target.path("rest").path("hello").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ToDoes.class); Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from @peeskillet, this is what I did.

I took the output XML - used http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html to create an XSD from it - then used `xjc` to generate a ToDoes class

```
ToDoes tds = target.path("rest").path("hello").request()
                        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(ToDoes.class);

List<ToDoes.ToDo> l = tds.getToDo() ;

for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
{
    System.out.println( "Summary"+i+":" + l.get(i).getSummary());
    System.out.println( "Summary"+i+":" + l.get(i).getDescription());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring-web API to call your REST service.

Add Spring-web to your class path, then use the below code:

```
List<MyBean> beans = null;
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate()
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyBean>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyBean>>() {};
Object requestParm = null;
ResponseEntity<List<MyBean>> response = template.exchange("http://example.com",HttpMethod.GET, requestParm, responseType);

if(response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK && response.hasBody()) {
            beans = response.getBody();
        }
```

Comment: How do I generate the MyBean class?

Comment: do you mean that how to convert the response from REST service to list of MyBean instances?! It will be deserialized automatically. but you should provide the the exchange method with your expected return type.

Comment: No. I mean how do I generate the source of the MyBean class? You are using List<MyBean> but where is the MyBean class?

Comment: MyBean is example of the response bean, based on your question use ToDo instead of MyBean

Comment: How do I get the source for the ToDo class if I am not the person who implemented the Web Service. For SOAP Webservices, I use JAX-WS or Axis to generate client classes - who I do I use here?

Comment: @user93353 you should just create a Class based on the xml you get. You can see that the Class should be named ToDo and that it has two attributes, description and summary. both Strings.
You might need to Annotate the class/setters with @XmlElement(name="NameInXMLResponse") if you want to use another  name than the ones in the response.

Comment: Before calling a service you should know how to integrate with the service, so you should know URL, HTTP method, Request format, Response format. Based on the response format you can create your bean.

lets say, the expected response is {"id": 10, "name": "user"} then you bean should be like this:

 Class MyBean {
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public int getId() {
   return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
   this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
   return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
  }
 }

Comment: @ThibaultFouquaert my question is whether there is a tool which allows me to create the class

Comment: In REST service there is no standard documentation like WSDL, so I think you should create the class manually!